# My Flutter loop the hit when i fill the textformfield

Tags: flutter, dart

So basically my flutter app keep on hitting the Future code again and again after i fill my textformfield

Here's my textformfield code :

```
TextFormField(
                        style: TextStyle(
                            color: Color(0xFF726951),
                            fontSize: 17.sp
                        ),
                        controller: NumberHolderController,
                        decoration: InputDecoration(
                            contentPadding:
                            EdgeInsets.only(left: 1.h),
                            enabledBorder:
                            OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide:
                              BorderSide(
                                color: Color(0xFF726951),
                                width: 0.h,
                              ),
                            ),
                            focusedBorder:
                            OutlineInputBorder(
                              borderSide:
                              BorderSide(
                                  color:
                                  Color(0xFF726951)),
                            ),
                            hintStyle: TextStyle(
                                color: Color(0xFF726951),
                                fontSize: 17.sp
                            ),
                            hintText: 'Nomor Tujuan',
                            border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                            focusColor: Colors.red,
                            errorStyle: TextStyle(
                                height: 0,
                                color: Colors.transparent)
                        ),
                        validator: (val) {
                          if (val.isEmpty)
                            return '';
                        }
                    ),
```

and Here's my Future Code :

```
Future  _InquiryPro() async {
  data = "https//sades.com/asd"
  return data;
 }
```

and here's how i call the future

```
FutureBuilder (
  future:_InquiryPro()
  builder : (context, snapshot) {
   if (snapshot.hasData) {
     print("get")
   } else {
     print("non")
   }
 }
)
```

but it dont even print what's on if else

it keeps on return

Answer (score 0):

Once state rebuild, future is getting called.  Create a state function variable for Future.

```dart
late final _future = _InquiryPro();
```

And provide this on `FutureBuilder`.

```dart
FutureBuilder(
  future: _future,
```

Comment: im using the older sdk, there's no late

Comment: you can remove late on that case and just use final . Also i think it is better to upgrade

Answer (score 0):

So this error is happened because my keyboard on the last screen is still active, so i just make the keyboard to be inactive then push to the new screen